# Prevent BlackBerry application from installing on older devices

Tags: blackberry

I'm developing an app for a BlackBerry which needs to have a minimum framework version: 4.5
I tried installing on a device with a 4.2 framework and gives an error about some rim.whatever.package not found.

So I'm not sure I can add version checking inside the app itself since seems it will not even load.

I know I can detect device version from the website where they get the app itself but was wondering if there's any option to prevent the app from installing if the minimum framework is not present. Or add some better error message on the application itself.

Answer (score 1):

> was wondering if there's any option to prevent the app from installing if the minimum framework is not present

Once the app is downloaded from server to device there are no means to prevent installation.

> Or add some better error message on the application itself.

OK, Bruce Eckel in his "Thinking in Java" writes:

> So the first time an object of type Dog is created, or the first time a static method or static field of class Dog is accessed, the Java interpreter must locate Dog.class.

This means you can do the version check unless the application workflow has reached the point where some absent class should be loaded. So (if RIM class loading implementation doesn't differ from Java SE) this looks like a tricky, but a possible thing.

Comment: I'll just add that the three ways for a standard user to install software on a BlackBerry (Desktop Manager, Over the Air, and AppWorld) all provide methods for the developer/vendor to prevent a COD file from being installed on the wrong version of the OS.

Comment: Yes, meaning that the startup version check implementation is very close to wasting developer's time.

Comment: Richard, this app is installed from a download on a client website. The way to prevent the installation is through something like this: [BB browser detection](http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/Web-and-WebWorks-Development/How-to-detect-the-BlackBerry-Browser/ta-p/559862)

Or there's any other option?